# Powershell script that outputs all workflows,their title and status from sharepoint 2013 site that has workflows attached to every list

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, powershell-script

The SharePoint 2013 site has a few subsites and each subsite has further subsites that have lists in it. To these lists there is a workflow attached.

How do I write a powershell script to retrieve the Title, status and workflow versions for all the workflows attached to these lists.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding that you have SharePoint 2013 enterprise edition and you want to get all the workflow details attached to all the lists in a site collection, you can use the below powershell code.

```
############################################################################################################################################ 
# Script that allows to get the workflow exectuion status for all the workflows deployed to a SharePoint Site 
# Required Parameters: 
#  -> $sUserName: User Name to connect to the SharePoint Site Collection. 
#  -> $sPassword: Password for the user. 
#  -> $sDomain: AD Domain for the user. 
#  -> $sSiteColUrl: Site Collection Url. 
############################################################################################################################################ 

$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread" 

#Definition of the function that gets the workflow exectuion status for all the workflows deployed to a SharePoint Site 
function Get-SPSitesInSC 
{ 
    param ($sSiteColUrl,$sUserName,$sDomain,$sPassword,$sCSOMPath) 
    try 
    {     
        Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"  -foregroundcolor Green 
        Write-Host "Getting the workflow execution status for all the workflows deployed in sSiteColUrl" -foregroundcolor Green 
        Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"  -foregroundcolor Green 

        #Adding the Client OM Assemblies 
        $sCSOMRuntimePath=$sCSOMPath +  "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
        $sCSOMWorkflowPath=$sCSOMPath + "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll" 
        $sCSOMPath=$sCSOMPath +  "\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"              
        Add-Type -Path $sCSOMPath          
        Add-Type -Path $sCSOMRuntimePath 
        Add-Type -Path $sCSOMWorkflowPath 

        #SharePoint Client Object Model Context 
        $spCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteColUrl)  
        $spCredentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($sUserName,$sPassword,$sDomain)   
        $spCtx.Credentials = $spCredentials  

        if (!$spCtx.ServerObjectIsNull.Value)  
        { 
            $spWeb = $spCtx.Web 
            $spLists = $spWeb.Lists 
            $spCtx.Load($spLists); 
            $spCtx.ExecuteQuery(); 

            $spWorkflowServicesManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($spCtx, $spWeb); 
            $spWorkflowSubscriptionService = $spWorkflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService(); 
            $spWorkflowInstanceSevice = $spWorkflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService(); 

            Write-Host "" 
            Write-Host "Getting all the Lists in $sSiteColUrl" -ForegroundColor Green 
            Write-Host "" 

            foreach ($spList in $spLists)          
            {    
                $spWorkflowSubscriptions = $spWorkflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($spList.Id); 
                $spCtx.Load($spWorkflowSubscriptions);                 
                $spCtx.ExecuteQuery();                 
                foreach($spWorkflowSubscription in $spWorkflowSubscriptions) 
                {             
                    Write-Host "**************************************************************************************" 
                    Write-Host "List: "$spList.Title " - Workflow: "$spWorkflowSubscription.Name -ForegroundColor Green 
                    Write-Host "***************************************************************************************" 
                    Write-Host "" 

                    $spCamlQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery 
                    $spCamlQuery.ViewXml = "<View> <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields></View>"; 
                    $spListItems = $spList.GetItems($spCamlQuery); 
                    $spCtx.Load($spListItems); 
                    $spCtx.ExecuteQuery(); 

                    foreach($spListItem in $spListItems) 
                    { 
                        $spWorkflowInstanceCollection = $spWorkflowInstanceSevice.EnumerateInstancesForListItem($spList.Id,$spListItem.Id); 
                        $spCtx.Load($spWorkflowInstanceCollection); 
                        $spCtx.ExecuteQuery(); 
                        foreach ($spWorkflowInstance in $spWorkflowInstanceCollection) 
                        { 
                           Write-Host "List Item Title:"$spListItem["Title"]  
                           Write-Host "Workflow Status:"$spWorkflowInstance.Status  
                           Write-Host "Last Workflow Execution:"$spWorkflowInstance.LastUpdated 
                           Write-Host "" 
                        } 
                    }                    
                    Write-Host "" 
                } 
            } 

            $spCtx.Dispose()  
        }         
    } 
    catch [System.Exception] 
    { 
        write-host -f red $_.Exception.ToString()    
    }     
} 

#Required Parameters 
$sSiteColUrl = "http://<Site_Collection_Url>/"  
$sUserName = "<SP_User>"  
$sDomain="<Domain>" 
$sPassword ="<User_Password>"  
$sCSOMPath="C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI" 

Get-SPSitesInSC -sSiteColUrl $sSiteColUrl -sUserName $sUserName -sDomain $sDomain -sPassword $sPassword -sCSOMPath $sCSOMPath
```

[Reference](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-get-the-workflow-7d00eed9)